# Update multiple rows in Android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have table contains columns id, name, profession, age, hobby, country, sex. Now I want to update the fields where sex is female and age is 30. All the fields are text (String). First, I am counting all the rows then running a loop to update the rows. Loop is running as per the total rows but rows are not updated... WHY? Where I have done the mistake? Here is my code:

METHODS FOR ANDROID SQLITE DATABASE QUERY:

```
public void updateUser(String newProfession, String newCountry, String sx, String ag) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE "+TABLE_USER+" SET "+KEY_PROFESSION+"='"+newProfession+"', "+KEY_COUNTRY+"='"+newCountry+"' WHERE "+KEY_SEX+"='"+sx+"' AND "+KEY_AGE+"='"+ag+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

public int countAll() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

CALLING THE METHODS

```
public void updateUsersClicked(View view) {
    int allData = db.countAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < allData; i++) {
        db.updateUser("SENIOR ENGINEER", "CANADA", "female", "30");
        System.out.println("T H I S    I S    T H E    R E S U L T: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I know but this is not my concern now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for updates.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL and requires one of the `moveTo...()` methods on the returned `Cursor` to execute it. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Also consider using `?` parameters with bind args in your SQL to avoid escaping special characters and being vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks... Your suggestion works for me. I should take good care of SQL injection for sure . Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the for loop
a single QSL "Update" query is enough if you want to update All the female with age 30.

If you are new to SQL you can view a simple example here:
[Simple SQL Update example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

If you want to do something else - please edit your question

Comment: Ya, but let us consider a case that I have age limit from 15 to 45. And I have to change only ages for 23, 43, 24, 27, and this value may vary time to time. What will be the case then?

Comment: This will change the WHERE clause of your query to someting like:

Comment: ...WHERE age>15 AND age<45 - and all the records that returns "true" for that condition will be updated to the value you put in the SET clause of the query

Comment: You neet to learn the UPDATE sql query syntax and code something that will transform the desiered logic to query in the right UPDATE syntax